# Weird browser behavior when opening webpage

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, web, browser-tabs

This happens quite often in both firefox and chrome and its quite annoying.

Scenario: I middle click on a link, opening a webpage in a new tab, the tab opens.

The pages loads, saying "waiting for ", but the tab icon is in stage 1, meaning it's trying to connect or something, and the page is still blank. What is really strange is that the browser address field doesn't have the address I clicked but "about:blank", so if I close my browser and re-open it, it would not have remembered which page I had opened, which is embarrassing.

It seems all browser hang at this step of opening a webpage, I wanted to know if it was a known issue or not, if it can come from a malware or other. It seems to happen in both mac and windows.

Comment: This is usually the step where it tries to resolve DNS... So your DNS server might be the cause... since it responds slow or not at all?

Comment: This problem only occurs when you use your middle button? What about when right clicking -> Open in new tab, or copying/pasting the URL?